# summation of exponential distribution with different parameters

Tags: matlab, exponential-distribution

I just calculated a summation of two exponential distritbution with different lambda.

It's known that summmation of exponential distributions is Erlang(Gamma) distribution.

However, when lamdbas are different, result is a litte bit different.

Anyway look at the following equations.

[image]

Now, problem is (alpha_1 λ_2-alpha_2 λ_1).

(alpha_1 λ_2-alpha_2 λ_1) becomes 0

Thus, last two terms go to infinite....

Is that true??

I make some simple matlab code for verification.

```
clc;
clear;
mu=[1 2];
a1 = mu(1)/(mu(1)+mu(2));
a2 = mu(2)/(mu(1)+mu(2));
n = 10^6;
x = exprnd(mu(1), [1, n]);
y = exprnd(mu(2), [1, n]); 
z = a1*x + a2*y;
figure
histfit(z, 100 ,'gamma')`
```

[image]

The figure is pdf of Z=alpha_1 * X + alpha_2 * Y.

This case is λ_1 = 1, λ_1=2. (The red line is gamma distribution.)

The result of matlab shows random variable Z is not infinite value.

What is the problom in my calculations??

Comment: See the two approaches demonstrated here at CV.SE. 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371768/distribution-of-sum-of-exponentials/371769#371769

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem in my integral calculation. In the 6th row, e^-(lambda2-alpha2*lambda1/alpha1) = 1, thus, there is no term alpha1/(alpha1*lambda2-alpha2*lambda1) in the 7th row.